# How to use SubtleCrypto in chrome (window.crypto.subtle is undefined)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cryptography

This is really embarassing

on virtually any site on the internet,

```
window.crypto.subtle
```

returns

```
SubtleCrypto {}
  __proto__: SubtleCrypto
```

in the chrome console (v61 (Official Build) (64-bit))

except for

my webpage, and [blank.org](http://blank.org)

where

```
window.crypto.subtle
```

returns

```
undefined
```

according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle
it's a read-only property that should always return a SubtleCrypto object.

what could I have done, or what has blank.org done that it could possibly not?

ps: in firefox it seems to work as intended on both my site and blank.org

Answer (score 76, accepted):

According to the [spec (via Github issues)](https://github.com/w3c/webcrypto/issues/28) a la this [Google page for WebCrypto](https://www.chromium.org/blink/webcrypto):

> crypto.subtle is supposed to be undefined in insecure contexts

Comment: It follows that it can only be used over https, as opposed to http.

Comment: I have noticed that `window.crypto.subtle` was available when targetting a local HTTP URL, such as http://localhost:8080/ for instance, which is quite useful for local web developments and tests out of the Internet.

Maybe local HTTP connections are considered as "secured contexts" as well?

Still, `window.crypto.subtle` is `undefined` with remote HTTP URLs.

(tested with Firefox/Windows, plus Docker in the local dev+test configuration)

Answer (score 10):

check your URL's

if it is 
`https://localhost:PORT`
 or `0.0.0.0:port`
 or `127.0.0.0:port`

change it to proper hostname URL something like
`http://localhost:PORT`

worked for me! Thanks @Zmart

Answer (score 6):

It would appear you have to use sites with https://...... and not vanilla http://....

From the spec - easy to miss (and linked by Zmart, above):

*Access to the WebCrypto API is restricted to secure origins (**which is to say https:// pages**).*

Comment: http://localhost and http://127.0.0.1 are also considered as secure contexts, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts

Comment: What is this answer adding to the already existing answers?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't run your website on `SSL` with `https` the answer is: You can't use `window.crypto.subtle`. You have to configure `SSL` for your webserver. Look in MDN docs about [Crypto.subtle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle) it has a big warning on top op the page saying *Secure context* which means it is only available on `https`.

**BUT** there is an alternative solution if you still need a support for `http` only. And it does not involve using `window.crypto.subtle` but other open-source third party library instead. Here is how:

You can use [Forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge) which is a crypto library that has same functionality like `window.crypto.sybtle` It has all crypto algorithms for your needs.

You can use forge instead of `window.crypto` when you run your services over `http`.

Be aware that APIs are very different and you need to write different code for cryptography using `forge` than using `window.crypto`.
You need to read [forge docs](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/blob/master/README.md) to make specific cryptography method work for your use case.
You **CAN NOT** use same code that works in window.crypto.subtle when using **forge** you need to find your own way how to use forge for encryption.

**For your reference** to see how `forge` vs `window.crypto.subtle` codes are different read below.

***Links** to original `window.crypto.subtle` based darkwire.io code and translated darkwire.io code that is using `forge` instead of `window.crypto.subtle`:*

- original code using `window.crypto.subtle`:
  [here](https://github.com/darkwire/darkwire.io/blob/master/client/src/utils/crypto.js)
- **code translated to use forge**, can run on `http` without `SSL`:
  [here](https://github.com/pavlobu/darkwire.io/blob/master/client/src/utils/crypto.js)

I had translated darkwire.io to use forge for my own project that runs on `http` and needs encrypted communication method between clients.