# Hash method returns undefined on Server

Tags: javascript, encryption, web, hash

im using the following Method to generate a hash value:

```
const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-1', msgBuffer);
```

It works fine when I have the html containing the script on my local machine. When I deploy it to the Test-Server it returns undefined.
Does someone have an idea what the Problem could be?

Snerps

Update:

I found out that the Problem only ocures while using chrome. Through the comment of Zmart on another question, I found out that crypto.subtle is supposed to return undefined in "insecure" context.
[How to use SubtleCrypto in chrome (window.crypto.subtle is undefined)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468104/how-to-use-subtlecrypto-in-chrome-window-crypto-subtle-is-undefined)

I used the script Alex commented to solve my issue. Im only generating single hashes, thats why performance won't be a issue with the script.

Comment: Reference to [`SubtleCrypto WebAPI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto)

Comment: What server are you running?

Comment: I actually have no idea... its deep inside a docker container.

Comment: There's a slight it's just not supported on that server or something is blocking it.

Comment: Where are you running your method in? A static `JS` file or in some kind of wrapper (docker).

Comment: The script is running inline on my html which lays on the server.

Comment: do you know any good alternative methods i could try?

Comment: What do you need it for? Are you encrypting something or do you just need a hash?

Comment: I need it to generate a hash of a string. I use the hash for a certificate.

Comment: And do you need the hash to be secure or just reliable?

Comment: It has to be secure.

Comment: Have a look [`here`](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html).

Comment: thanks, I'll try that! I would preffer the Mozilla Api but if that doesn't work I guess I don't have many other options.

Comment: Try it and let me know, otherwise we'll get Mozilla API to work.

Comment: You might already have checked these things, but since you didn't say . . . Are you sure that `msgBuffer` is defined? Are you sure that `crypto.subtle.digest` actually exists on the server? Are you checking the return value immediately after calling the function, so there's no chance that something is overwriting `hashBuffer`?